# PHP time() is not calculated

Tags: php, time

I'm a little puzzled by the following

```
  echo "<p>" . time() . "</p>"; // current unix timestamp
  echo "<p>" . time() - 60*60*1 . "</p>"; // 1 hours ago
  echo "<p>" . date('H:i',time() - 60*60*1 ) . "</p>"; // 1 hours ago
```

returns

```
 1351193453
 -3600
 20:30
```

Why is not `time()-3600` evaluated when standing by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an operator precedence issue. Subtraction is evaluated after concatenation. Wrap brackets around it, and it'll be fine:

```
echo "<p>" . (time() - 60*60*1) . "</p>";
```

Comment: Concatenation is evaluated first, but it is returning `-3600` instead of `1351193453-3600`, which is puzzling

Comment: It's trying to subtract 3600 from "<p>1351193453", which evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo "<p>" . (time() - 60*60*1) . "</p>"; // 1 hours ago
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/2ZhtWJVZ)

Comment: secs difference in correction of a typo make people downvote, thats just sad

Comment: @coder1984 I didnt downvote. +1 for helping out! but as I could see it the parantheses were first correct on andrewsis answer.

Comment: I didnt say you did, you may accept any answer, thats your choice.

Comment: I downvoted, and the reason was because it was simply wrong. Missing parentheses are not a typo, it was a copy of the text in the question, it took a lot longer than "secs" to correct. The timing as I observed it was: correct answer created, 2 or 3 minutes later this answer was created, then about a minute after that this answer was updated to be identical. There's no benefit in having duplicate answers.

Comment: @AD7six: First of all, the answers are placed bottom-to-top time-wise. If it was edited after 2-3 mins after the correct(above) answer, my answer would be on the top, also mentioning the edit time. The reason, there is no edit time shown, and the above answer coincides with my time, proves that it was just mere secs. Moreover, it wasn't missing parentheses, it was just wrongly placed. As mentioned above, the OP had seen the wrongly placed parentheses as well.

Comment: the order of the answers isn't particularly important - the impression I have is you created the answer reloaded the page, saw the error and copied the other answer. `time() - (60*60*1)` is not a typo - it's simply wrong. Because the creation times are nolonger shwn to the minute - I could have inverted the creation order in my previous reply but that means your answer existed for **minutes** with the wrong text, and in the mean time someone else answered correctly. My opinion is unchanged.

Comment: The purpose of my answer was to help the OP, not to judge or change opinions. Saying that, it was really nice of you to own up to the downvote after **10 hours**, especially when you were so keen to downvote within **minutes**.